# How do I fix the SDL Error: Invalid haptic device identifier?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

In my mod of the *Half-Life SDK,* I thought it would be nice to implement controller rumble when firing a weapon using the already-included SDL2 library; though it was trickier than I thought.

The file [ev_hldm.cpp](https://github.com/phoenixprojectsoftware/Aura-CL/blob/master/cl_dll/ev_hldm.cpp) in the clientside binary contains functions which are called every time a weapon is fired - each weapon has its own "event," or "EV" function. I decided to add the first rumble test to the MP5; therefore I went down to `EV_FireMP5`.

First, though, I added the includes for the SDL2 headers I'd need:

```
#include "../external/SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "../external/SDL2/SDL_haptic.h"
#include "../external/SDL2/SDL_joystick.h"
#include "../external/SDL2/SDL_timer.h"
```

Then, I got to work on the code in `EV_FireMP5` with some help from [this tutorial.](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/20_force_feedback/index.php)

Below my viewpunch code, I added this:

```
SDL_Joystick* gameController = NULL;
        SDL_Haptic* ControllerHaptic = NULL;

        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK) < 0)
        {
            gEngfuncs.Con_Printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
            // Check for any joysticks
            if (SDL_NumJoysticks() < 1)
            {
                gEngfuncs.Con_Printf("No controllers detected.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                // Load the joystick
                gameController = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);
                if (gameController == NULL)
                {
                    gEngfuncs.Con_Printf("Unable to open controller. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                }
                else
                {
                    // Get the haptic
                    ControllerHaptic = SDL_HapticOpenFromJoystick(gameController);
                    if (ControllerHaptic == NULL)
                    {
                        gEngfuncs.Con_Printf("Controller does not support vibration. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Get the init rumble
                        if (SDL_HapticRumbleInit(ControllerHaptic) < 0)
                        {
                            gEngfuncs.Con_Printf("Failed to init rumble. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        if (SDL_HapticRumblePlay(ControllerHaptic, 0.75, 500) != 0)
        {
            gEngfuncs.Con_Printf("Failed to play rumble. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
        else
        {
            SDL_HapticClose(ControllerHaptic);
        }
```

However, it does not work. The in-game console prints this upon firing:

```
No controllers detected.
Failed to play rumble. SDL Error: Haptic: Invalid haptic device identifier
```

Either it isn't detecting a controller which supports rumble or it isn't detecting any controller at all. I am using an Xbox Series controller connected via Bluetooth; I've also tried an Xbox 360 controller which presents the same issue.

Is there something wrong with my code or should I use XInput instead?

Comment: Try adding `SDL_INIT_HAPTIC` to the `SDL_INIT( )` call. So it should be `if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK | SDL_INIT_HAPTIC) < )` Also I think connecting it by Bluetooth might have something to do with it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I tried adding that, however the 'invalid device identifier' error is still present